# Increasing the size of array creates some problem

Tags: c++

I tried to check, what is the largest size of array, which can be created in CPP. I declared a "int" array and kept increasing the array size. After 10^9 the program started crashing, but there was a serious error for array of size 5*10^8 and more(even when program did not crash). The code used and the problem is following :

```
#include<iostream>
int ar[500000000];
int main()
{
    printf("Here\n");
}
```

The above code runs successfully, if the size of array is reduced to 4*10^8 and lesser. But, for array size greater than 5*10^8, the program runs successfully but it does not print any thing, also it does not get crashed, or gave any error or warning.

Also, if the array definition is local then there is no such error, after same limit the program gets crashed. It's when using the global definition of array, the program does not get crashed nor does print anything.

Can anybody please explain the reason for this behavior. I've understood that the size of array will vary for different machines.

**I've 1.2 GB of free RAM. How am I able to create the local integer array of size 4*10^8. This requires around 1.49GB, and I don't have that much free RAM.**

Comment: The maximum size for an array is dependent on how much memory your machine has. The programs crash because you don't have enough memory to allocate (on the stack)!

Comment: How large an array can be depends on the hardware.  This isn't really all that large.  You could be running on anything, a camera, a coffee pot chip, a super computer, so we'd need more info to answer.

Comment: @mikhailvs It's a global variable, won't be created on the stack.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @mikhailvs I realize it is implementation dependent, but it would be a naive implementation that goes and sticks global arrays onto the stack. What's the benefit?

Comment: @Praetorian I dunno, in truth I didn't realize it was a global when I first read the post.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is: why are you using globals? And to make it worse, it's a static raw array?

As suggested already, the memory used to hold global variables is being overflowed (and it possibly wrote over your `"Here\n"` string).

If you really need that big of an array, use dynamically-allocated memory:

```
int main() {
   int* bigArray = new int[500000000];
   // ... use bigArray here
   delete[] bigArray;
}
```

Comment: Should be using `unique_ptr` instead. `std::unique_ptr<int[]> intarr(new int[500000000]);`

Comment: Or just use std::vector. <code>std::vector<int> array(500000000,0)</code> since unique_ptr might not be available to him

Comment: using the local array of large size the program gets crashed, and if the program runs successfully it also, runs expectantly. But using global array, even when the program is not crashed the code does not run as expected.

Comment: That's because local arrays go on the stack, an even smaller area than that of global vars.  new/malloc goes on the heap, the largest area available to your program.

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry, but introducing dependency on boost or C++0x would be just ridiculous in a small code snippet whose only goal is to demonstrate dynamically-allocated memory.

Comment: @Christian : I totally disagree. In real code, use of raw `new`/`delete` should always be avoided, so why demonstrate the **incorrect** way to do things in a small code snippet? How is that beneficial to anyone?

Comment: @Christian Rau I agree introducing boost for this is overkill, but C++0x is the (soon to be) standard, and there is no overhead for using its features since compilers have already implemented several of these. In this case, you could use `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter too, or do you consider `std::tr1` an inexcusable dependency too?

Comment: @ildjarn I see your point, but you should keep answers clean and not introduce unneccessary weight, that is completely unimportant for the answer. His next comment will be "what does unique_ptr mean?, what is it for?, what about using int* instead of unique_ptr?, shouldn't I call delete[]?...

Comment: @Praetorian It is just unimportant for the demonstration of the answer.

Comment: @Christian : `unique_ptr` is as lightweight as it gets -- indeed, in practice, using raw pointers vs. `unique_ptr` will compile to the exact same machine code (assuming no custom deleter). Overall, I think it's better that he learns about smart pointers now rather than getting in the habit of not using them, and that answers shouldn't encourage bad practices or non-idiomatic approaches.

Comment: @ildjarn This is nothing about lightweightness of the generated machine code, but about the lightweightness of the answer concentrating on a given topic. The answer doesn't encourage a bad practice, as the code snippet is not intended to be copied as is, but taken as a demonstration of the described direction. In what regard the reader follows this direction specifically is up to him. It is just not part of the question and answer. Although I understand that a little comment about using smart pointers would be good for beginners, it does not fit into the code sample.

Comment: @ildjarn And using `new` and `delete` is part of the C++ programming language and should be understood by every C++ programmer, together with their implications and responsibilities. Everything beyond that is an application of these concepts. We should also not encourage people to forget about memory usage. I don't consider using `new` and `delete` as bad-practice in any regard. Otherwise I would be better off with an automatically garbage collected language.

Comment: @Christian : I agree that `new` and `delete` are part of the C++ programming language and should be understood by every C++ programmer -- but just like `goto`, the best thing they can be told is to _avoid_ them unless/until they actually know what they're doing. The reason C++ has the stigma of being too easy to shoot yourself in the foot is because of things exactly like this -- people go for the short and easy answers because "they should understand what's going on anyway", when it would be just as short and easy to demonstrate the **correct** approach (RAII).

Comment: @ildjarn I see your point and maybe a small note under the answer might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

C++ inherently doesn't restrict the max limits on the array size. In this case since it is a global variable it will be outside the stack as well. The only thing I can think of is the memory limit on your machine. How much memory does your machine has? How much memory is free before running your program?